# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester Apache 7

Tags: jsf, tomcat7

Hi i am trying to use following technologies together :

- MyFaces 2.1.12
- jstl 1.2
- Apache 7

but when trying to run my application, i got the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.<init>(DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getUnmarshaller(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:93)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getStandardFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:135)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:370)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:143)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester
```

Wich is very disturbing, because I have linked the commons-digester3-3.2.jar in my project, put it in the lib directory under "Web-INF" and added it in the java build path...what's wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use commons-digester version 1.8 . commons-digester3 has a lot of changes already.